# Why is my Lambda Function not working through AWS Mobile Hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

EDIT: I got it to work - see my answer below

I'm trying to get a basic lambda function to be run on my iOS device, BUT it doesn't work! It works when I test it on Lambda Management, but gives me the following error when I try to get it going on Mobile...

"The operation could not be completed...Access denied exception."

The same error is given when I try to run a lambda function that doesn't exist at all.  I just built the sample project on xCode, and the demo lambda function AWS gives works, but the one I created for some reason is not being accessed, even though I gave it all of the same settings.

What do I need to do to make the lambda function accessible?

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the lambda function? Using AWS iOS SDK?

You should use AWS Cognito to authenticate and add a permission to your cognito policy to call the Lambda function.

You can find more information on how to authenticate with Cognito on this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html

Comment: I got it to work using my answer below... thanks for responding though!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the first time I created the function, it wasn't in the mobile application project I was working on, even though I linked to build a new one through that page.

I used a different link which took me to edit the sample lambda function and from there I created a new function.  I then had to go back to the mobile hub and check the box next to the new function I created.

I then restarted the application and the function worked.